Following googles tutorial automotive-design-compose, Invalid @Design parameter type (ImageReplacementContext) -> Bitmap?
I am following the Google tutorial from https://github.com/google/automotive-design-compose (I am using Android Studio Meerkat | 2024.3.1 Canary 3).
When I try to run the project which is pretty much the first step of the tutorial, I get following error:
> Task :app:kspDebugKotlin FAILED
e: [ksp] Invalid @Design parameter type (ImageReplacementContext) -> Bitmap?
e: [ksp] Invalid @Design parameter type (ImageReplacementContext) -> Bitmap?
e: Error occurred in KSP, check log for detail

The only references to that is:
import com.android.designcompose.ImageReplacementContext

and later in
@DesignDoc(id = "3z4xExq0INrL9vxPhj9tl7", customizationInterfaceVersion = "0.8")
interface Tutorial {
    @DesignComponent(node = "#stage", isRoot = true)
    fun Stage(
        @Design(node = "#live-time") liveTime: String,
        @Design(node = "#title") title: String,
        @Design(node = "#subtitle") subtitle: String,
        @Design(node = "#long-title") longTitle: String,
        @Design(node = "#photo") photo: (ImageReplacementContext) -> Bitmap?,
        @Design(node = "#icon") icon: (ImageReplacementContext) -> Bitmap?,
        @Design(node = "#timer") timer: String,
        @Design(node = "#buttontext") buttonText: String,
        @Design(node = "#boldtitle") boldTitle: String,
        @DesignVariant(property = "#media/now-playing/play-state-button") playState: PlayState,
        @Design(node = "#media/now-playing/play-state-button") onPlayPauseTap: TapCallback,
        @DesignContentTypes(nodes = ["#GridItem"])
        @DesignPreviewContent(
            name = "Browse",
            nodes =
                [
                    PreviewNode(1, "#GridItem=Rect"),
                    PreviewNode(3, "#GridItem=Square"),
                    PreviewNode(1, "#GridItem=Rect"),
                    PreviewNode(6, "#GridItem=Square"),
                    PreviewNode(1, "#GridItem=Rect"),
                    PreviewNode(6, "#GridItem=Square"),
                ],
        )

but easier to directly check in the repo:
https://github.com/google/automotive-design-compose/tree/main/reference-apps/tutorial
